# Does GiGABYTE H61M-S2P-B3 (rev. 1.0) supports GeForce GTX 680?

Tags: motherboard, gpu

Does GiGABYTE H61M-S2P-B3 (rev. 1.0) supports GeForce GTX 680 or GeForce GTX 750 or GeForce GTX 580?

If the PCIe slot supports these gpu or not

I find that GiGABYTE H61M-S2P-B3 (rev. 1.1) supports 3rd generation PCI-Express interface but I don't find anything that says GiGABYTE H61M-S2P-B3 (rev. 1.0) supports 3rd generation PCI-Express interface.

Comment: I want to know If the PCIe slot supports these gpu or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Gigabyte H61M-S2P-B3 v1.0 specs](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3952#sp):

> (All PCI Express slots conform to PCI Express 2.0 standard.)

PCIe devices are backward compatible, so a 3.0 card will run in a 2.0 slot.

For more information on that, perhaps check out these existing SU questions:

- [Will a PCI Express x16 2.0 slot work with a PCI Express x16 3.0 graphic card](https://superuser.com/questions/786125/will-a-pci-express-x16-2-0-slot-work-with-a-pci-express-x16-3-0-graphic-card)
- [A PCI Express 3.0 Video Card into a PCI-E 1.0 x16 slot](https://superuser.com/questions/427196/a-pci-express-3-0-video-card-into-a-pci-e-1-0-x16-slot?rq=1)